# Two python scripts and want them to work together

Tags: python, python-3.x

First, I have two python scripts. let's see

```
#Script1.py
import time
i = 0
while True:
  i = i+1
  print(i)
  time.sleep(1)

#Script2.py
from script1 import i
print(i)
```

Second, I run Script1

```
Result of Script1
1
2
3
.
.
```

Then, run Script2 continuously

```
Result of Script2
1
2
3
.
.
```

The problem is I want Script2 print the current value of Script1 not rerun Script1 like :

```
Run Script1 :
1
2                Run Script2 :
3                3
4                4
5                5
```

Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use threading to run things in parallel. Consider this code:

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

class Task(Thread):
  i = 0
  def run(self):
    while True:
      self.i += 1
      sleep(1)


t = Task()
t.start()
sleep(5)
print(t.i)
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that all the code in your module Script1 gets called every time you import it. This means that importing your module has the same effect as running it.

One common way to handle this is to add the following statement, which prevents execution unless the module is directly run:

```
# Script1
import time
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # ...
```

However, from your desired output it seems you want to read from the first running script while it is running. This code here will not achieve that because it is blocking (i.e. it does not yield to other requests, it will execute entirely, in this case forever, before it lets anything else happen).